# Darktable startup problem: symbol not found

Tags: darktable

Darktable 2.0.3-1 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 fails to start with this error:

```
darktable: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/../lib/darktable /libdarktable.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5Exiv213XmpProperties10registerNsERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: 32/64bit? How did you installed it? (here it starts just fine) Did it work at some point or it is the first time that you try to use it and it doesn't work? If you try with another user, does it work?

Comment: 64 bit machine.  Installed yesterday with 'apt-get install darktable'.  I've also installed all system updates and rebooted.  The machine was running 14.04 with darktable from a PPA previously, and it all worked fine.  Upgraded to 16.4.1, and darktable was uninstalled automatically during the upgrade.

Comment: Same problem when I use a test account that had never run darktable before.

Comment: % file libdarktable.so 
libdarktable.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=c37493534ade290e39e545e4c3da51dc0fe1a4f4, stripped

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by uninstalling `libexiv2-14` (which also forced uninstallation of KDE, maybe you can keep it broken until reinstallation). Apparently this library was installed from a PPA before.

After reinstalling Darktable, which also reinstalled `libexiv2-14` it worked again.

Edit: Just had the same problem again (on another machine), and google let me to my answer. It worked again.